# What is the proper way to handle menu items in a master/detail flow?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I built a master/detail flow based on the generated Android Studio example.  I am using `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` to allow my list and detail fragments to contribute to the action bar menu.  The problem is that if the user switches back to portrait from landscape then the detail fragment is still around and still contributing to the action bar menu when really only the list is showing.  What is the proper way to implement menu items such that they won't linger when the fragment is not visibly present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use an [isVisible()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isVisible%28%29) check in the detail fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu` to conditionally `inflate` the menu.