# How to remove lingering menu items from nested fragments in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I'm working on a Android project that has a `TabHost` with four main tabs which each have a corresponding `Fragment`.

`[ Tab 1 ] [ Tab 2 ] [ Tab 3 ] [ Tab 4 ]`

As an additional feature I would like to add a nested `TabHost` to `[ Tab 3 ]`:

`[ Subtab 1 ] [ Subtab 2 ]`

Each `Subtab` has a corresponding `Fragment` as well.

I've successfully done this but I'm having some very strange behavior. `[ Subtab 1 ]` and `[ Subtab 2 ]` both have their own unique menu items and when I switch from `[ Tab 3 ]` in either `Subtab` to a different main `Tab`, the `Subtab`'s menu items stay in the navigation bar.

Am I missing something obvious? Do I need to wire up `[ Tab 3 ]` to specifically release these menu items or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was able to find an answer here:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/24017261/4762063

The work around is to conditionally inflate the `Fragment`'s menu, only if the `Fragment` is visible.